# Distribution of Irreducible Factors of Polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: probability-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Consider monic polynomials of degree $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. These polynomials can be written in the form $$f(x) = x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_1x+a_0; a_i\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace.$$ Let $\phi(x)$ denote a random variable in this set of polynomials, with uniform distribution: $$\mathbb{P}(\phi = f)=\frac{1}{2^n}.$$ 
Factor $\phi$ into a product of irreducible factors, and let $C_i$ denote the number of irreducible factors of degree $i$.

I am interested in the limiting distribution of the process $(C_1,\ldots, C_n)$. What is the distribution of the process $(C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n)$?

I am unsure of the distributions of the $C_i$'s due to the fact that two distinct polynomials can have the same value of $C_i$ for all $1\le i\le n$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_k$ be the space of polynomials of degree $k$. It is a $\Bbb F_2$-linear space of dimension $k$.

Let $P$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$.

For any $k$ the multiplication by $P$ map $\mu_P : S_k \to S_{k+n}$ is a measure preserving bijection from polynomials of degree $k$ to polynomials of degree $k+n$ divisible by $P$.

Therefore, the probability that a random polynomial of degree $k$ is divisible by $P$ is $2^{-n}$ if $k \ge n$, the probability that it is twice divisible is $2^{-2n}$ if $k \ge 2n$, and so on.

So in the limit, the law of the number of occurences of $P$ follows an exponential distribution $P(N_P = m) = 2^{-mn}(1 - 2^{-n})$

Furthermore, if you take a finite number of irreducible polynomials $P_1,P_2, \ldots, P_m$, in the limit the numbers $N_{P_1},N_{P_2},\ldots,N_{P_m}$ are all independant from all the others (for any integer $B$, their bounded versions $\min(N_{P_i},B)$ are independant when $k$ becomes larger than something like $(B+1)\sum \deg P_i$)

In http://oeis.org/A001037 you can get the number of irreducible polynomials of each degree.

If $a_n$ is the number of irreducible polyonmials of degree $n$ then after adding all the $C_{P_i}$ of degree $n$ together, you get (in the limit)

$P(C_n = m) = \binom {m+a_n-1}{a_n-1} 2^{-mn}(1-2^{-n})^{a_n}$

Comment: Thanks. The $C_i$'s are dependent, so how can we find the law of the process $(C_1,\ldots, C_n)$ (or its limiting distribution as $n\to \infty$)?

Comment: I am not completely certain of what it would mean concretely to find a law for a sequence of infinitely many variables. When you only look at finitely many of them, they behave independantly and things are fine, but taken all together you can ask a lot of complicated questions. For example if you look at all the degree $n$ polynomials, $\sum kC_k = n$, so that thing tends to infinity. Some other question would be what percentage of the factorisation has even degree and I haven't answered any of that at all for example.

Comment: I mean take the law of the finite sequence (up to $C_n$) then take the limit of that expression. The $C_i$'s should be dependent for my random variable since (for example) if $C_1=n$ then $C_i=0$ for all $i>1$.

Comment: I don't think that makes sense, unless you want to look at the limit of $D_{1,n} = C_{1,n}/n$ as $n \to \infty$, in which case it converges to $D_1 = 0$ with probability $1$.